# didSelectItem UITabBar issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

There is an issue with `didSelectItem` `UITabBar`.
The app consists of 2 View Controllers connected via `UITabBar`.
2 tab bars: Client - Settings

```
    tabBar.delegate = self;
    NSMutableArray *tabBarItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Client" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_zakaz.png"] tag:0];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Settinga" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_settings.png"] tag:1];

    [tabBarItems addObject:tabBarItem1];
    [tabBarItems addObject:tabBarItem2];

    tabBar.items = tabBarItems;
    tabBar.selectedItem = [tabBarItems objectAtIndex:0];

- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{

    int selectedTag=tabBar.selectedItem.tag;
    NSLog(@"%d",item.tag);

    if (selectedTag==0)
    {
        // NSLog;
    }
    else if(selectedTag==1)
    {
        SettingsViewController *ViewController = [[SettingsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self presentViewController:ViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
    }
}
```

From client view controller I can easily switch to Settings VC. 
`didSelectItem` correctly handles events.

But I can't switch back from settings to client.

Seems that `didSelectItem` doesn't correctly register the touch. 
At the moment to perform this operation I need to touch the tab bar and hold it.

Please help me D:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are going wrong way. You should not do like that with tabbar, should do as below instead:

```
UITabbarController *tabbarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];

MyViewController1 *viewController1 = [[MyViewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController1" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
MyViewController2 *viewController2 = [[MyViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController2" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

[tabbarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil] animated:NO];
[tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0]; // To show viewController1.

self.window.rootViewController = tabbarController;
```

Then tabbar controller will do the rest, you don't have to care about didSelectItem anymore.

P/S: if you want to stick to your choice, you should use tabbar.selectedIndex instead.

Comment: If this answer helps you solve your issue then pls mark it as the ANSWER.

Comment: It's interesting to know the reason of problem.

Comment: didSelectItem doesn't correctlywork. I need to touch the tab bar and hold it. In 1st ViewCOntroller it works perfect, but not working in 2nd VC..

Answer (score -1):

Try this, use item.tag

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
    {

        if (item.tag == 1)
        {
            // NSLog;
        }
        else if(item.tag == 2)
        {
            SettingsViewController *ViewController = [[SettingsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil];
            [self presentViewController:ViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
        }
    }
```